# How to get JS class name from class, but not from instance?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

I have the following class

```
class MyClass {

   constructor() {
   }

   doIt() {
      var i = 10;
   }
}
```

How, can I get the name of the class (string "MyClass") without creating instance of this class?  I tried:

```
console.log(MyClass);
console.log(MyClass.constructor);
console.log(MyClass.constructor.name);
```

But can't get what I need.

Comment: If you can write `MyClass`, then you already know the name…!?

Comment: MyClass.name ....

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/name

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the class property

```
class MyClass {

   constructor() {
   }

   doIt() {
      var i = 10;
   }
}

console.log(MyClass.name)
```

Working fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/ghdb6ebc/1/